# unable to resolve react-navigation-stack from app.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, installation

Only beginnings of boilerplate and upon attempting to run the app I get the message:

> Unable to resolve "react-navigation-stack" from "App.js"

I've tried several different types of installation of `react-navigation-stack`

This one was received from:
 https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

```
yarn add react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the main `react-navigation` library as well, along with the dependencies used:

```
yarn add react-navigation
yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```